# How does 一面向 break down in 她一面走着，一面向旁边张望着?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

This is from the children's book 七色花:

> [image]
>
> 她一面走着，一面向旁边张望着，念着招牌上的字，...
> As she walked, she looked sideways and read the words on the signboard ... [[Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#zh-CN/en/%E5%A5%B9%E4%B8%80%E9%9D%A2%E8%B5%B0%E7%9D%80%EF%BC%8C%E4%B8%80%E9%9D%A2%E5%90%91%E6%97%81%E8%BE%B9%E5%BC%A0%E6%9C%9B%E7%9D%80%EF%BC%8C%E5%BF%B5%E7%9D%80%E6%8B%9B%E7%89%8C%E4%B8%8A%E7%9A%84%E5%AD%97%EF%BC%8C)]

I'm wondering how 一面向 breaks down.  I'm confused because there's multiple possibilities:

- [一面](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E4%B8%80%E9%9D%A2/) (yī miàn) = "one side"
- [面向](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%9D%A2%E5%90%91/) (miàn xiàng) = "face" (in the sense of facing a certain direction)
- [向旁边](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%90%91%E6%97%81%E8%BE%B9) (xiàng pángbiān) = "sideways", or perhaps "to the side"

There also seems to be a grammar structure in play here: 一面[something],一面[something else].

**Question**: How does 一面向 break down in this snippet?

Comment: Judging from the structure, it looks similar with the construction of "一边……一边……".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you suspected, the structure “一面....一面...” is in play, and the snippet should be understood as “她 一面 走着，**一面 向**旁边 张望着。”

The structure “一面...一面...” is used to associate two verbs when the subject performs them at the same time, in this sense it is the same as the structure “一边...一边...”：

> 她**一面**走着，**一面**向旁边张望着。
>
> 她**一边**走着，**一边**向旁边张望着。

These two sentences both express:

> She looks around **while** walking.

Answer (score 1):

According to [现代汉语八百词](https://www.amazon.cn/dp/B001198GSW), `一面……一面……` is used to indicate two or more actions are performed simultaneously. They are used before a verb. The first `一面` can sometimes be omitted.

Breaking it down from your sentence, you'll get:

`她一面[Adv.] 走着[V]，一面[Adv.] 向旁边[Adv.] 张望着[V]`

which means "As she walked, she looked sideways" (the same as you translated). Other examples:

> 1. 他们**一面**走，**一面**挥舞花环，**一面**欢呼。
> 2. 他（**一面**）用心地听着，**一面**记着笔记。

There's a side note, though. `一面……一面……` could also mean `一方面……一方面……`, which means "on one side ..., on the other side ...". Usually `另` is added on the second `一面` on this construction, e.g:

> 说明书土**一面**印的是中文，**另一面**印的是英文